# python help! If/else statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I have been learning python through code academy.  It asked me to create a if else statement that prints the users input, but if there is no input print "empty".  I did pass the tutorial but when there is a user input it prints both the users input and "empty".

here is my code:

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"

original = raw_input("what is your name?")
length = len("original")

if length > 0:
    print original

else: length < 0
print "empty"
```

Notice that print under else is not indented.  I thought you had to indented it, but when i do it gives me an error.

Comment: Lose the condition after the else.

Comment: It's not even correct, it would be <= 0. Of course, there are other problems with his program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have a couple issues with your code. First I believe you should change your assignment of `length` to:

```
length = len(original)
```

That way you get the correct length of the string you binded to the name `original`. If you use `len("original")`, you will pass the string "original" to the `len()` function, and it will just count the characters in that string. Regardless of what the user of your program inputted, your length will always be 8, since that's how many characters are in the string `"original"`

Also keep in mind that the `len()` function will never return a negative value. So testing if `length < 0` doesn't make sense. You probably wanted to test if it equals 0. It seems as if you were trying to use an `elif` statement.

Try:

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"

original = raw_input("what is your name?")
length = len(original)

if length > 0:
    print original

elif length == 0:
    print "empty"
```

`elif` statements let you test conditions just like `if` statements. `elif` is short for "else if".

Furthermore, as @chepner pointed out in the comments, there is no need to even test the second condition at all. You can just as easily go with:

```
else:
    print "empty"
```

The `else` syntax is not followed by any condition. It automatically enters the indented block of code if the other conditions evaluate to False.

Comment: If length is not greater than zero, and cannot be less than zero, the only remaining option is 0. There's no need to replace `else` with `elif length == 0`.

Comment: I know, I was just trying to adhere to his original logic as closely as possible.

Comment: @TrentBurkenpas then you must reward someone with the checkmark, or you will not get much help in the future!

Answer (score 4):

Was the `length < 0` intended to be a comment? You need the comment character `#`.

```
else: # length < 0
    print "empty"
```

It's wrong anyway, it should be `length <= 0`.

Without a comment character it was being interpreted as the statement to use as the `else` clause. It didn't create an error since `length < 0` just generates a boolean result that you didn't do anything with, but it prevented you from having another statement as part of the `else`.

Answer (score 2):

```
else: length < 0
print "empty"
```

should be

```
elif length == 0:
   print "empty"
```

Python has significant whitespace, things that are indented the same are in the same scope.

Comment: `length` will never be smaller than 0; just `else` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

There is a a statement after else.

```
else: length < 0
print "empty"
```

Maybe you are looking for an (`elif` is another way to check another condition after the `if` if the previous `if` fails.)

```
elif length <= 0:
```

or just a plain

```
else:
   print "empty"
```

it will never go past zero anyways you could have a `==` conditional for zero and it would work.

```
elif length == 0:
```

this is probably the best way there is no need to check another condition.

```
if length > 0:
   print original
else: 
   print "empty"
```

also just a side note `length = len("original")`

there is not suppose to be quotation marks around original because its a variable :). You will just be getting the string "original" not the actual stuff inside of the variable.

The end result ..

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"

original = raw_input("what is your name?")
length = len(original)

if length > 0:
    print original
else: 
    print "empty"
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, it is not `len("original")` it is `len(original)`. If you use quotes you are making it a constant value, "original", rather than a variable named original.

Second, instead of checking the length of the string you should use this

```
if original:
    # Type here what happens if the string is not empty
else:
    # Here what happens if the string is empty
```

By Python standard any collection, including strings, equals `false` if it is empty(aka contains no elements) and `true` if it contains any elements.

Answer (score 0):

To check if there is an item in a list, simply do this:

```
if List_name:
    {code here}
    ...
```

So, your code should very simply look like this:

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"
original = raw_input("what is your name?")
if original:
    print original
else:
    print "Empty"
```

It's that easy :D